# Is there any native functions in Linux that load and save images without using external libraries?

Tags: c++, c, linux, save-image, loadimage

In Windows `LoadImage` API loads image to the memory.

FreeImage (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net)  is a cross-platform library for loading and saving images, but I want to use functions like `LoadImage` in Windows, that do not depend to any external libraries like FreeImage.

Is there any native functions in Linux that load and save images without using external libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Loading and saving images is really not the job of an Operating System kernel like Linux. A kernel manages memory, IO and CPU resources, and that's it. Everything else should be done by user-level code.

Answer (score 4):

Linux is a kernel, it's not even an operating system really. There are no libraries in there to help you with stuff like this.

Within Windows it's actually the same, except that Windows includes a load of libraries by default.

If you want something similar on Linux, you'll have to install some libraries too.