# how to load an image in C++ from local directory

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix

I need to load and pass an image to a code. I am trying to modify part of a code from this [library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182242/Transforming-Images-for-Fun-A-Local-Grid-based-Ima). This library is designed for windows and the below is the code which I need to modify for linux environment. Can some one help me with its linux equivalent.

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ m_bmpImage;

System::String^ sFile = gcnew System::String(txtFilePath->Text);
m_bmpImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(sFile);

    BitmapData^ bmpData = m_bmpImage->LockBits(
                System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, m_bmpImage->Width, m_bmpImage->Height),
                ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb);
            ImageData imgData;
            imgData.Resize(bmpData->Width, bmpData->Height, 3, bmpData->Stride);
            memcpy(imgData.Data, (char*)(void*)bmpData->Scan0, bmpData->Stride*bmpData->Height);

            m_bmpImage->UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Comment: This is not C++ it is C++/CLI which won't work on linux unless there is some mono magic you can use.

Comment: @doctorlove Yes it wont work. I need its equivalent for Linux?

Comment: There are many image loading libraries available on Linux. Both specific for a single image type (like libpng for PNG image, libjpeg for JPEG images, etc), then libraries which uses these specific libraries to be able to load multiple formats. A quick search should find you something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862362/is-there-any-native-functions-in-linux-that-load-and-save-images-without-using-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `PGM` file format for grayscale or `PPM` file format for RGB because they are trivial to read from code, then use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to do the conversion (the linux command is for example `convert myfile.jpg myfile.ppm`). ImageMagick supports a huge number of file formats including rather exotic ones.

For example C code for reading a PPM file just using `<stdio.h>` is

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename.ppm", "rb");
if (f != NULL && fscanf(f, "P6 %i %i 255%*c", &w, &h) == 2) {
    unsigned char *pixels = malloc(w*h*3);
    if (!pixels) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (((int)fread(pixels, 1, w*h*3, f)) == w*h*3) {
        fclose(f);
        printf("Image is %i x %i pixels\n", w, h);
        ... process image ...
    } else {
        printf("Image file truncated\n");
        exit(1);
    }
} else {
    printf("Invalid image file\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

PGM (grayscale) is identical with `P5` instead of `P6` and just has one byte per pixel instead of 3.

Note that formally PPM/PGM files are a bit more annoying to read (e.g. there could be comments in the header) but those generated by `convert` are clean (for example those produced by `gimp` are not, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

FreeImage is good: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net; 
But I've always preferred OpenCV for every image processing stuff: http://opencv.org

Both are cross-platform.

Comment: Yes I had a try with opencv and left in the middle because of lack of time. Thanks anyways for the suggestion.